# Files.ReadWrite.Selected microsoft graph api permission - how it works

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

i am trying to understand how Files.ReadWrite.Selected  permission provided here in https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes works.
can someone explain it in layman term.

i have a web app which uses microsoft v2 endpoint and generates the token, i have given the permission as

```
 Scope = "openid email profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.Selected",  





    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        ClientId = SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                        Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, SettingsHelper.Authority, "common", "/v2.0"),
                        Scope = "openid email profile offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.Selected",
                        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = false
                        },
}
```

i want to know how this scope works, is it like i need to go to one drive and first select particular folder and if my app tries to read that folder, then it works. can i create file in selected folder using the same scope

Answer (score 0):

This scope isn't useful for Microsoft Graph. The scope exists to support the [Office 365 File Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-file-handler-extensions) feature and isn't designed to be used for applications who want API access to files. For those scenarios, you need to use Files.ReadWrite to get access to the user's files.

I'll log a bug to have the description of these permissions updated to be more clear about the indented use case.