# MsGraph permission Files.ReadWrite.All is there an alternative?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have Files.ReadWrite.All as an option to access files and folders through the app via MS Graph on the behalf of the user (Delegated). However, I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the scope of the app. Because that seems unnecessarily wide permissions ?

I have looked at Files.ReadWrite.Selected but it does not seems to propose a list of options, neither on the user of the app side nor on the global admin dashboard of Micorosoft Azure. I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386148/files-readwrite-selected-microsoft-graph-api-permission-how-it-works). The answer seems to have indeed been added to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference?view=odsp-graph-online). So at least this functionality (labelled as preview) does not seems to have changed since 2016.

I just want to make sure I did not miss something.